Keyboard driver BSOD -> cannot enter the Read Completion Routine
I am writing a low filter driver for the keyboard in windows 10.
It's purpose it to read the keystrokes and log them (currently, it should only read the scan codes since I have not yet written the code to process and log the keystrokes)
However I have come across a problem, I get a BSOD whenever I try to type something.
From my winDBG prints I have noticed that the driver does not even enter the Read Completion Routine function.
this is what a got after debugging in winDBG :
[+] Driver Entry Loaded.
[+] Device attached successfully.
9492031250 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
9492343750 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
9502656250 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
9505312500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
9515625000 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: IDLE
9516562500 - STORMINI: StorNVMe - POWER: ACTIVE
[+] Intercepting keyboard input (IRP_MJ_READ)
* Fatal System Error: 0x000000d1
                       (0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000002,0x0000000000000001,0xFFFFF80018A02F17)

Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

this is the code of the driver :
#include <ntifs.h> 
#include <wdm.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA {
    USHORT UnitId;         // Reserved for legacy hardware (often unused now).
    USHORT MakeCode;       // Scan code representing the key.
    USHORT Flags;          // Flags indicating the type of key event (press/release, etc.).
    USHORT Reserved;       // Reserved (for alignment or future use).
    ULONG ExtraInformation; // OEM-specific extra information (usually 0 or unused).
} KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA, * PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA;

typedef struct _DEVICE_EXTENSION {
    PDEVICE_OBJECT NextLayerDeviceObject;  
} DEVICE_EXTENSION, * PDEVICE_EXTENSION;


/*
* Print debugging msg into winDBG menu
* in order for winDBG to see msg you need to
* 1. break
* 2. type ed nt!Kd_IHVDRIVER_Mask 8
*
* @param text - the string to be printed
*/
void debug_print(PCSTR text)
{
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, text));
}

NTSTATUS KeyboardIrpReadCompletionRoutine(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp, PVOID Context)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);

    debug_print("[+] Entered KeyboardIrpReadCompletionRoutine succsefully.\n");

    // Check the IRP status
    if (Irp->IoStatus.Status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        debug_print("[+] Got a key press.\n");
        // Validate the SystemBuffer
        if (Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer != NULL) {

            debug_print("[+] Validated the SystemBuffer.\n");

            PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA keyData = (PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
            ULONG numKeys = (ULONG)(Irp->IoStatus.Information / sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA));

            debug_print("[+] Created the PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA struct.\n");

            for (ULONG i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
                char buffer[100];
                sprintf(buffer, "Key Pressed: %x\n", keyData[i].MakeCode); // IN THE FUTURE, WE WILL USE THIS DATA AND TRANSPORT IT TO USERMODE
                debug_print(buffer);
            }
        }
        else {
            debug_print("[-] SystemBuffer is NULL.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        debug_print("[-] KeyboardIrpReadCompletionRoutine failed.\n");
    }

    // Complete the IRP
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    // Return the IRP status
    return Irp->IoStatus.Status;
}



NTSTATUS KeyboardIrpDispatchRead(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    debug_print("[+] Intercepting keyboard input (IRP_MJ_READ).\n");

    // Validate DeviceExtension and NextLayerDeviceObject
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION deviceExtension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    if (deviceExtension == NULL || deviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject == NULL) {
        debug_print("[-] DeviceExtension or NextLayerDeviceObject is NULL.\n");
        Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST;
        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
        return STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST;
    }

    // Set up the completion routine
    IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);
    IoSetCompletionRoutine(Irp, KeyboardIrpReadCompletionRoutine, NULL, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);

    // Pass the IRP down the stack
    return IoCallDriver(deviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject, Irp);
}


VOID DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    debug_print("[+] Driver Unloading.\n");

    PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject = DriverObject->DeviceObject;

    // Detach and delete device objects
    while (pDeviceObject) {
        PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDeviceExtension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pDeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
        if (pDeviceExtension && pDeviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject) {
            IoDetachDevice(pDeviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject);
        }
        IoDeleteDevice(pDeviceObject);
        pDeviceObject = pDeviceObject->NextDevice;
    }
}


/*
  This function serves as the entry point for the driver. It prints a debug message,
  initializes the driver name, and creates the driver by calling `IoCreateDriver`.
  input: None
  output: Returns the status of `IoCreateDriver`, which indicates whether the driver was successfully created.
*/
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    debug_print("[+] Driver Entry Loaded.\n");

    // Set unload routine
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    // Set up a dispatch routine for IRP_MJ_READ
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = KeyboardIrpDispatchRead;

    // Create device object
    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION),
        NULL, FILE_DEVICE_KEYBOARD, 0, TRUE, &DeviceObject);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        debug_print("[-] Failed to create device object.\n");
        return status;
    }

    // Initialize the device extension
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDeviceExtension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
    RtlZeroMemory(pDeviceExtension, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION));

    // Get the target keyboard device
    UNICODE_STRING targetDeviceName;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&targetDeviceName, L"\\Device\\KeyboardClass0");

    PFILE_OBJECT fileObject;
    PDEVICE_OBJECT targetDevice;
    status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&targetDeviceName, FILE_READ_DATA, &fileObject, &targetDevice);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
        debug_print("[-] Failed to find keyboard device.\n");
        return status;
    }

    // Attach to the device stack
    PDEVICE_OBJECT lowerDevice = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack(DeviceObject, targetDevice);
    if (!lowerDevice) {
        ObDereferenceObject(fileObject);
        IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
        debug_print("[-] Failed to attach to device stack.\n");
        return STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE;
    }

    // Save the lower device object
    pDeviceExtension->NextLayerDeviceObject = lowerDevice;

    // Release the file object
    ObDereferenceObject(fileObject);

    // Clear the DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING flag
    DeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

    debug_print("[+] Device attached successfully.\n");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

thank you for taking the time to read my problem

First, it might be more straightforward to use the built-in hooking mechanism instead of rolling your own. Secondly, at the minimum a stack trace is required to even attempt to diagnose what is going wrong.
